# Powershell ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I am successfully u sing `ffmpeg` via `powershell` to compress video files, however I can't get the compression to occur in a single location, I only have success when I make separate inputs and outputs.

For example, this command will be successful:

```
ffmpeg -y -i \\path\$x -vf scale=1920:1080 \\diff_path\$x
```

this will not do anyhting or will corrupt the file:

```
ffmpeg -y -i \\path\$x -vf scale=1920:1080 \\path\$x
```

I think I understand why this doesn't work, but I'm having a hard time finding a solution. I want the script to address a file and compress it in it's current location, leaving only a single compressed video file.

Thanks all

Comment: Let ffmpeg create a new file in the destination folder named like "OriginalFileName.tmp" (or whatever). When ffmpeg has finished, delete original file and rename temp file to original file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Not the answer you want, but FFmpeg is not able to perform in-place file editing, which means it has to make a new output file.

Comment: You are right, it is not the answer I want! I'll see if we can change our process a bit to account for that.

Going to wait a bit to see if there's any other suggestions and if not will mark yours as the answer. Thanks so much.

Comment: Why not wait until compression has finished and move the file to the location you desire using PowerShell @Garrett?

Comment: good question @SantiagoSquarzon , the source location and destination happen to be the same path with our current workflow. Going to modify it a bit. Maybe just move the file being compressed to a propagation location and move it back to the intended location once done. Thanks everyone.